# Unable to get stream via NetStream method in AS2

Tags: action, actionscript-2, red5, netstream

Here is my Code:

```
<pre><code>
     var my_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    my_nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/");
    var my_ns:NetStream= new NetStream(my_nc);
    my_video.attachVideo(my_ns);
  //my_video.play();
   my_nc.onStatus = function(info){
trace(info.code);
  }
 my_ns.onPlayStatus  = function(info) {
trace("Stream" + info.code);
    //if (info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
     // trace("flv has finished playing")
  //}
};
```

I am not able to get stream published by RED5. Help please

Answer (score 0):

From you code snippet it is not even clear if you want to broadcast your webcam or play a remote stream.

Also coding of client side is done in ActionScript3 these days. ActionScript2 receives no more updates since 2006. ActionScript3 contains codecs and methods that are not even available in ActionScript2 as AS2 only runs up to Flash Player SWF8.
SWF9 and later only runs AS3 code (although you can still run AS2 inside it, but the Flash Player will only give you API functions based on SWF8 then.)
Current SWF version is SWF11.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#Timeline_by_ActionScript_version

Sebastian

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation, in first phase, i want to get stream (clinet side ) and then i'll go for publish_stream.

Comment: have a look at the demo applications at the website: http://red5.electroteque.org/dev/doc/html/Red5DemoApplications.html